# has_secure_password - only hashes or encrypts as well?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bcrypt-ruby

I'm not entirely sure if, when you add `has_secure_password` in a Rails model, there's any encryption involved. I know there's definitely hashing with a salt, but is there encrypting? bcrypt can use blowfish, but is it being used in `bcrypt-ruby` (the gem behind all of this)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR : `has_secure_password` will make you use Bcrypt's hash function when using the `self.password=` method.

---

Let's look at the code of [`has_secure_password`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_secure_password) :

```
    # File activemodel/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb, line 53
    def has_secure_password(options = {})
      # Load bcrypt gem only when has_secure_password is used.
      # This is to avoid ActiveModel (and by extension the entire framework)
      # being dependent on a binary library.
      begin
        require "bcrypt"
      rescue LoadError
        $stderr.puts "You don't have bcrypt installed in your application. Please add it to your Gemfile and run bundle install"
        raise
      end

      include InstanceMethodsOnActivation

      if options.fetch(:validations, true)
        include ActiveModel::Validations

        # This ensures the model has a password by checking whether the password_digest
        # is present, so that this works with both new and existing records. However,
        # when there is an error, the message is added to the password attribute instead
        # so that the error message will make sense to the end-user.
        validate do |record|
          record.errors.add(:password, :blank) unless record.password_digest.present?
        end

        validates_length_of :password, maximum: ActiveModel::SecurePassword::MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH_ALLOWED
        validates_confirmation_of :password, allow_blank: true
      end
    end
```

We can see that it does **NOT** hash/encrypt anything. Nevertheless, we notice:

```
      include InstanceMethodsOnActivation
```

If we go on the documentation of [`InstanceMethodsOnActivation`](https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/blob/master/lib/bcrypt/password.rb) we get the following code :

```
def password=(unencrypted_password)
  if unencrypted_password.nil?
    self.password_digest = nil
  elsif !unencrypted_password.empty?
    @password = unencrypted_password
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST : BCrypt::Engine.cost
    self.password_digest = BCrypt::Password.create(unencrypted_password, cost: cost)
  end
end
```

Therefore, `has_secure_password` does not encrypt/hash anything BUT includes `InstanceMethodsOnActivation` module. This module defines the `password=` method. The important part of this method is:

```
self.password_digest = BCrypt::Password.create(unencrypted_password, cost: cost)
```

Let's now go see [`BCrypt::Password.create`](https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/blob/master/lib/bcrypt/password.rb) 's code:

```
  def create(secret, options = {})
    cost = options[:cost] || BCrypt::Engine.cost
    raise ArgumentError if cost > 31
    Password.new(BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(secret, BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt(cost)))
  end

  def valid_hash?(h)
    h =~ /^\$[0-9a-z]{2}\$[0-9]{2}\$[A-Za-z0-9\.\/]{53}$/
  end
end
```

In this method, we notice in particular:

```
Password.new(BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(secret, BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt(cost)))
```

So it seems to be a hash, which is logical (you don't want to decrypt a password anyway).